# Why I got "Failed to transfer file RELEASE does not allow version" in Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

My Maven project's structure like this:

```
testMaven(root)
--brother-module
    --brother-grandson-module
--son-module
    --grandson-module
```

Obviously my dependency of parent modules and children modules follows my file directory.

and when I compile or install the grandson-module,It's can be passed and successd.

but when I make grandson-module depend on brother-grandson-module

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test.cx</groupId>
            <artifactId>brother-grandson-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and while show

```
Could not transfer artifact test.cx:brother-grandson-module:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT from/to nexus (http://10.10.0.89:8088/nexus/repository/maven-releases/): Failed to transfer file: http://10.10.0.89:8088/nexus/repository/maven-releases/test/cx/brother-grandson-module/1.0-SNAPSHOT/brother-grandson-module-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom. Return code is: 400 , ReasonPhrase:Repository version policy: RELEASE does not allow version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT.
```

and then after my install the brother-grandson-module,it will success again.

I wonder why cause it.please tell my why it works like this.Thanks.

Comment: Snapshots are not releases. Nexus treat those differently

Comment: Snapshots basically is work in progress and isn't stable. It's recommended to use released artifacts as they are considered stable.

Comment: Use a `RELEASE` or deployed version and it should work!.